# What is the API for launching audio control center in iOS application?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I would like to launch audio control center from my application and switch audio output.

Music app has its function. How can I do it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: See [AVRoutePickerView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avroutepickerview)

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I could display it!